# what is mean by @ in the makefile gnu make?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, makefile, omake

For example if i write

```
       ->@ %echo "Hello"
```

it print Hello in the console

```
       ->Hello
```

what is @ in the case and %?

Answer (score 0):

By default GNU Make print the command before executing it (i.e. recipe echoing), using @ you'll hide it like `set -x/set +x` in bash script...

src: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing